# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'int' and 'list'

Tags: python, typeerror, python-3.6

Can someone help me fix this TypeError? I am trying to raise 5 by a number n and print its last 2 digits

```
     from sys import stdin, stdout
     n = [int(x) for x in stdin.readline().rstrip().split()]
     l = 5**n
     res = str(l)
     stdout.write(res(2)+res(1))
```

Comment: If you're trying to do that to One number, why are you using split() and lists?

Comment: Look at the error.  What does it say?  Now look at `5**n`.  `n` is a list.  You can't use a list as an exponent.  You need to ask yourself what you're trying to do.  Do you perhaps want `[5**v for v in n]`?  Or perhaps `5**n[0]`?  Or maybe something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you are trying to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
from sys import stdin, stdout


numbers = [int(x) for x in stdin.readline().rstrip().split()]
res = [5**x for x in numbers]
stdout.write(str(res[1] + res[0]))
```

This gets input from `stdin` and splits it into a list of `ints`. Then it makes a new list consisting of 5 raised to the `x` where x is each value from the old list. Finally we write the value of the first and second index added together to `stdout`. Note, this will throw an error if less than 2 numbers are inputted.